# Any Other Way To Speed Up Code For INSERT INTO STATEMENTS for N Rows?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, ado

Im making Codes Inserting Data into a autonumber Columns to a table that composes of Two COlumns.
My Table is Access and Front End is Excel. My Access Table contains ID (which is AutoNumber) and Paycode which is base on a cell. I need this codes to use it as Unique IDs in which later on will post it back to Ms Access separate Table.

```
Sub ImportJEData()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection 'dim the ADO collection class
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset 'dim the ADO recordset class
Dim dbPath
Dim x As Long
Dim var
Dim PayIDnxtRow As Long

'add error handling
On Error GoTo errHandler:

'Variables for file path and last row of data
dbPath = Sheets("Update Version").Range("b1").Value
Set var = Sheets("JE FORM").Range("F14")

PayIDnxtRow = Sheets("MAX").Range("c1").Value

'Initialise the collection class variable
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

'Create the ADODB recordset object.
'Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset

'Connection class is equipped with a —method— named Open
'—-4 aguments—- ConnectionString, UserID, Password, Options
'ConnectionString formula—-Key1=Value1;Key2=Value2;Key_n=Value_n;
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
'two primary providers used in ADO SQLOLEDB —-Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0 —-Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
'OLE stands for Object Linking and Embedding, Database




Do

    On Error Resume Next 'reset Err.obj.

         'Get the Max ID +1
        Set rst = Nothing
        Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset
        SQL = "SELECT Max(ApNumber)+1 FROM PayVoucherID "
        rst.Open SQL, cnn

        'Check if the recordset is empty.
        If rst.EOF And rst.BOF Then
        'Close the recordet and the connection.
        Sheets("Max").Range("A2") = 1
        Else
        'Copy Recordset to the Temporary Cell
        Sheets("MAX").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

        End If

        'Insert the Data to Database And Check If no Errors
        Sql2 = "INSERT INTO PayVoucherID(ApNumber)Values('" & Sheets("MAX").Range("A2") & "') "
        cnn.Execute Sql2

Loop Until (Err.Number = 0)

'And if No errors COpy temporary to NEw Sub Temporary Data for Reference
Sheets("LEDGERTEMPFORM").Range("D1").Value = Sheets("MAX").Range("A2").Value



'Securing ChckID Seq Number
'ADO library is equipped with a class named Recordset
For x = 1 To PayIDnxtRow
        Set rst = Nothing
        Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset
        rst.AddNew
        'Insert the Data to Database And Check If no Errors
        Sql2 = "INSERT INTO PayPaymentID(ApNumber)Values('" & Sheets("LEDGERTEMPFORM").Range("B2") & "') "
        cnn.Execute Sql2

Next x
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset
    SQL = "Select PayID From PayPaymentID where APNumber = " & Sheets("LEDGERTEMPFORM").Range("B2") & " order by PayID "
    rst.Open SQL, cnn
    Sheets("PaySeries").Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset rst




    Set rst = Nothing


rst.Close
' Close the connection
cnn.Close
'clear memory
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

'communicate with the user
'MsgBox " The data has been successfully sent to the access database"

'Update the sheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
errHandler:

'clear memory
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Export_Data"
End Sub
```

In this section Below Would like to know if theres another way without using or even faster type of loop.

```
'Securing ChckID Seq Number
'ADO library is equipped with a class named Recordset
For x = 1 To PayIDnxtRow
        Set rst = Nothing
        Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset
        rst.AddNew
        'Insert the Data to Database And Check If no Errors
        Sql2 = "INSERT INTO PayPaymentID(ApNumber)Values('" & Sheets("LEDGERTEMPFORM").Range("B2") & "') "
        cnn.Execute Sql2

Next x
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset
    SQL = "Select PayID From PayPaymentID where APNumber = " & Sheets("LEDGERTEMPFORM").Range("B2") & " order by PayID "
    rst.Open SQL, cnn
    Sheets("PaySeries").Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset rst
```

Comment: The answer in this link is the way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722159/ms-access-vb-net-how-can-i-insert-rows-from-an-excel-sheet-data-into-ms-access

Comment: Thanks but seems like his problem was connectivity. The codes above works fine for me its just It took 30 to 40s to process I was expecting at max 10seconds. Before I added up this codes it only took me 5s to process. What I need is a work around with the codes specially at For Next

Comment: Whoops, wrong link :) Here's the right one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161865/using-excel-vba-to-export-data-to-ms-access-table

Comment: In your `x` loop you're adding new records into rst but then running a SQL insert to update the database - why not add the records to rst and then run updatebatch?

Comment: @Miqi180 Thanks again Almost there but I dont understand this line [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & dsh ''''   speciall the dsh... I didnt see any range in there.. Anyway I only want to Insert Same data a thousand times in a X row

Comment: @TimWilliams Would like to do that but it wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Ive figured it Out it went better from 40 to 19s Thanks to the idea of @miki180.

Heres my code below starting from DO...

```
Do
On Error Resume Next 'reset Err.obj.

     'Get the Max ID +1
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset
    SQL = "SELECT Max(ApNumber)+1 FROM PayVoucherID "
    rst.Open SQL, cnn

    'Check if the recordset is empty.
    'Copy Recordset to the Temporary Cell
    Sheets("MAX").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    'Insert the Data to Database And Check If no Errors
    Sql2 = "INSERT INTO PayVoucherID(ApNumber)Values('" & Sheets("MAX").Range("A2") & "') "
    cnn.Execute Sql2

Loop Until (Err.Number = 0)

xlFilepath = Application.ThisWorkbook.FullName

SSql = "INSERT INTO PaypaymentID(Apnumber) " & _
"SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & xlFilepath & "].[MAX$G1:G15000] where APNumber > 1"

cnn.Execute SSql

 Set rst = Nothing
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset

 SQL = "Select PayID From PayPaymentID where APNumber = " & _ 
Sheets("LEDGERTEMPFORM").Range("B8") & " order by PayID "

rst.Open SQL, cnn
Sheets("PaySeries").Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset rst
```