# inserting multiple rows with 1 query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have problem in inserting multiple rows with 1 query using ms access 2003. When I use `INSERT INTO` like the code below

```
INSERT INTO Employee values ('1','b','c');
INSERT INTO Employee values ('2','d','e');
```

the problem, ms access always appears pop up **characters found after end of SQL Statement**. So, are there any way to insert the data into the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Access SQL you can't combine two `INSERT` statements.  You could run each of them separately.  But if you need to do it with a single statement, you will need to use a more complex query.

```
INSERT INTO Employee
SELECT '1','b','c'
FROM Dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '2','d','e'
FROM Dual;
```

`Dual` is a custom table designed to always contain only one row.  You can create your own `Dual` table using the instructions from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7933927/77335).

However, you don't actually need a custom table for this purpose.  Instead of `Dual`, you can use any table or query which returns only one row.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )

INSERT INTO Employee values (('1','b','c'),('2','d','e'));
```

refer here

[SQL code to insert multiple rows in ms-access table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212943/sql-code-to-insert-multiple-rows-in-ms-access-table)

Comment: i use this method, but there still appear a pop up "missing semicolon(;) at the end of SQL statement

Comment: add a semicolon at last @FenediW

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it appears MS Access is not compatible and only allows single query insert unless you have a source table. If you can hook this to a tool that can execute the query, then you can make a loop to run the multiple insert

Answer (score 0):

**Use this confirm working query:**

```
INSERT INTO Product (Code,Name,IsActive,CreatedById,CreatedDate )

SELECT * FROM (

SELECT '10001000' AS Code,'Blackburn sunglasses' AS Name,1 AS IsActive,1 AS CreatedById,'2/20/2015 12:23:00 AM' AS CreatedDate FROM Product

UNION SELECT '10005200' AS Code,'30 panel football' AS Name,1 AS IsActive,1 AS CreatedById,'2/20/2015 12:23:09 AM' AS CreatedDate FROM Product

) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
insert into animal (animal_id, name, species)
values ( (1,'Foxi Maxi', 'dog'), (2, 'Dodo',' duck') , (3, 'Garfield', 'cat' ) )
```

use this example